# SoapUI behaviour when teststep invoked from testcase is different

Tags: soapui

I have an interesting behavior in relation to SoapUI 5.0.0.

I have a HTTP Test Request Step configured to post text/xml.

Within the request I have attribute expansion on some of the attributes in the request similar to:

```
FirstServiceDate="${=pluto.ServiceDate.adjustDate(modelItem, 1)}"
```

Note that the reference is calling a java function that I have created and placed into a jar file in the bin/ext folder of my installation.

Now when I send the request using the request steps play button attribute substitution occurs as expected and the correct value for the attribute is placed in the Raw message content and dispatched appropriately.

However, when I run the test case that includes the test step the substitution instead placed the following error message into the output:

```
No signature of method: static pluto.ServiceDate.adjustDate() is applicable
```

This would indicate that when the test step is being run that it can no longer find/use the java class in question.

Is this a deliberate limitation of the non-pro version in relation to request substitution or is there something more I need to do to get the class found when running a test case?

EDIT:
Have just tested against the PRO version as well.  This limitation/bug is still present unless I need to locate the jar file somewhere else.

Comment: Try placing your .jar _also_ in `$SOAPUI_HOME/lib`. There was a bug in SoapUI a while back, which _still_ might not have been fixed.

Comment: @SiKing - thanks for the response.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  It seems the TestCaseRunner class must set up it's own classloader that restricts what is loaded and available in the non-pro version.

Comment: This _should_ work in the non-Pro edition as well!

Comment: It seems in 5.0.0 it doesn't work, non-pro and pro editions.

Comment: If you have a -Pro license, you could submit this as a bug. http://www.soapui.org/Support/support-overview-place.html

Comment: Planning to, only have a pro trial licence to check if it happens in it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in the wording of the error

```
No signature of method .... is applicable
```

SoapUI is actually finding the library, however the type of object that is passed through as a modelItem is different depending on whether it is being run from the TestStep or the TestCase.

By changing the type of the modelItem to an AbstractModelItem the code then works.

Be aware that different mechanisms provide different modelItem classes.